# Python String Cleaning

Tags: python, regex, pyqt

I am writing a program in PyQT that needs to take messy strings and clean them up.  The possible input values are extremely variable.  For example I would like to take the strings:

```
"Seven_Pounds_(BDrip_1080p_ENG-ITA-GER)_Multisub_x264_bluray_.mkv",  
"The_Birds_1963_HDTV_XvidHD_720p-NPW.avi",  
"1892.XVID.AC3.HD.120_min.avi"
```

and turn them into:
    "Seven Pounds",
    "The Birds",
    "1892"

I have considered using re to escape expressions, but this method seems likely to fail for the last example.  The program [Media Gerbil](http://mediagerbil.codeplex.com/) uses the [google diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) algorithm to deal with string cleaning.  This seems like a better alternative, but I am not sure how to implement it.
Is there another, more effective method for cleaning strings in Python/PyQt, or is the regex or diff-match-patch the best route to follow?

Comment: first and foremost, you have to *define* what the expected result has to look like.

Comment: I think he did: "turn them into: 'Seven Pounds", 'The Birds', '1892'"

Comment: I'd try Google's method.

Comment: you could split on _ or . and query against imdb http://www.imdbapi.com/

Comment: @Derek Springer: He gave a "user" specification: three examples with no clue as to what "clean" means. Also half-described a "solution": diff-match-patch (diff between his input and what??). This is a programming forum, not a business analysis forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your example:

```
import re

a="The_Birds_1963_HDTV_XvidHD_720p-NPW.avi"
b="Seven_Pounds_(BDrip_1080p_ENG-ITA-GER)_Multisub_x264_bluray_.mkv"
c="1892.XVID.AC3.HD.120_min.avi"

def cleanit(str):
    result = []
    l = re.split('[_.]',str)
    flag = 0
    if re.match('^[a-zA-z]+',l[0]):
        flag = 1
    elif re.match('^[0-9]+',l[0]):
        flag = 2

    if flag == 1:
        for x in l:
            if not re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+',x):
                break;
            result.append(x) 
        return " ".join(result)

    if flag == 2:
        for x in l:
            if not re.match('^[0-9]+',x):
                break;
            result.append(x) 
        return " ".join(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print cleanit(a)
    print cleanit(b)
    print cleanit(c)
```

will print:

```
kent$  python cleanit.py
The Birds
Seven Pounds
1892
```

Comment: Thank you for the concrete example, it works well with the example strings I gave.  It seems that re is the way forward, and your script gives me a good place to start from.  Thank you

Comment: While this example does produce the desirable results for his 3 given examples, it makes the assumption that numbers after the title should be discarded. And it would break if the movie was "Toy Story 2"

Comment: true! not only xxx 2, but also something like 8mm, my codes doesn't work either. I think a more intelligent algorithm is needed if want to do it perfectly. e.g. how to distinguish "Lenin in 1918" and "The Birds 1963" ?  maybe query imdb is a good idea if the file names are complete title and all files are movies.

Comment: Ya thats what a few of us are suggesting in these various answers. Ultimately he does need to take his conservatively cleaned "pre-title" and run a match through an online movie database.

Comment: Adding "if len(x)<=2: result.append(x)" after "if not re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+',x):" in the first flag fixes the "Toy Story 2" problem (for movies with less than 99 sequels - if they have more I don't want them in my app anyway :)).  for the "88 Minutes" problem I think matching against a purge list, as suggested by jkerian, is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of diff-match-patch, match being the closest to what you are talking about, it seems to me that its maybe not the best solution, as match apparently wants to find specific patterns (not regex rules)?

I think you might want to define a series of regex rules, such as underscore being treated like a space between words, and any non- [a-zA-Z0-9_]+ possibly signaling the end of the title. You would have to at least make the assumption that your title starts from the beginning of the string, and then pattern match until a "non-word" character is reached.

Maybe something like this?

`rx = re.compile(r'([a-zA-Z\d_]+[a-zA-Z\d])[_.]?')`

But unfortunately, as mentioned in another of these answers, there is no way to really deal with "The Birds 1963". I think the solution is a combination of assuming where the title should start and possibly stop, and having the list of common tags to strip out maybe.

**Edit** - Thought of some more info

Maybe once you have narrowed down your potential title as far as you can get it, you could THEN do a google diff-match-patch against maybe an API search in imdb.com, and find the closest match to a real title

Comment: I think this is the route I will follow.  Narrow down title with regex -> query API -> ask user if this is the right title.

Answer (score 2):

I actually did this at one point... you basically follow a series of steps

- Eliminate anything in []'s, ()'s or {}'s
- Remove the file extension
- Now split on [\s.-_]

In your case, you'll get:

```
Seven Pounds Multisub x264 bluray
The Birds 1963 HDTV XvidHD 720p NPW
1892 XVID AC3 HD 120 min
```

Now you basically keep a list of words to purge from the list before you look at it. Obvious ones from this example are x264, Multisub, bluray, HDTV, XvidHD, Xvid, HD, 720p, 1040p, AC3. Note that you'll want to do case-insensitive compares here.

Note that this list will expand manually as you go through a collection, and that leaves you with

```
Seven Pounds
The Birds 1963
1892 120 min
```

This is probably about as good as you'll get for a semi-automated system. One of the above methods would tell you to purge numbers that don't appear at the front, but I'd point out that you'll mess up things like "Toy Story 2".

In my case, I did the above processing, and then tried to figure out which directory patterns matched for archival. Then I had a curses-based interface that allowed me to scroll through and manually correct the script's conclusions (including renaming).

EDIT: On second thought, my script actually made the assumption that a *second* set of numbers (as well as everything afterwards) could be safely removed. These are all heuristics though, and you *will* run into exceptions. Adding that step would have corrected the last example title to `1892`.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the examples it looks like it will be extremely tricky, regardless of technique. How should the program know that `1963` isn't part of the title of the middle movie? Maybe your best bet is to have a list of acronyms and then truncate the string from the first matching acronym and forwards. It would give you `The Birds 1963` to deal with, but I really see no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Cut by underscores, spaces, dots.

Filter out obvious parts like *x264* or *BDRip* or *multisub*.

Query IMDB for a movie with these words in the name :)